# How exactly does dotnet restore and buid/publish work with wildcard package references?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget-package-restore, dotnet-cli

I have a solution file which has 3 projects. ProjectA.csproj, CoreModels.csproj and ProjectB.csproj.

- CoreModels references a nuget package from a private repo. The references is using a wildcard as seen below since we are in early stages of development

`<PackageReference Include="NewProvider" Version="1.0.1-beta.*" />`

- Both 'ProjectA' and 'ProjectB' references the above 'CoreModels'. Everything builds fine in local
- However in build sometimes we get error saying "dll with version x.x" not found when using swashbuckle cli to generate swagger json by passing in the dll. Basically the root cause is that 'ProjectA' is referencing to 'NewProvider' dll version that is newer than the one referenced by 'ProjectB' and the dll for the later project is the one passed onto the swagger cli. Even if swagger is not in play, when running the api, same exception is thrown in the same line in startup.cs.
- The build pipelines does the below operation in order:

  - dotnet restore - From pipeline log, ProjectA is restored first followed by ProjectB. I see 'CoreModels' being restored in both these cases
  - dotnet test - Even though I have added --no-restore flag, I see 'CoreModels' restored for the first dotnet test execution. This is followed by 2 other test project all having references to 'CoreModels' but log shows that nothing is restored. 'All projects are up-to-date for restore.' is what the log says
  - dotnet publish 'ProjectA' and then another dotnet publish 'ProjectB'. Log says 'All projects are up-to-date for restore.'
  - The output is added to artifacts

. **Now if I use dotpeek, I see that 'ProjectA' references, for example lets say version 2 of NewProvider.dll and 'ProjectB' references version 1**.

This doesnt happen always, I believe this is happening when we try to push a new version of 'newprovider' nuget package around the same time the pipeline is running causing two versions to be picekd up. I am not sure how to prove this though. I assumed that when you do dotnet restore the packages are fixed. Does wildcard cause problems? Dotnet restore is happening for each project so will it be benificial if I run it against sln and not csproj. Any idea how to ensure the dll version remains same for all projects. We need to use wildcard for now.